# Have Categories navigation always active in mobile

Tags: category

www.undergrounddynamics.com

Hello, let see if I can explain this correctly.

I am trying to have my categories drop down always show or remain open instead of having someone click the button on the side to force it open.(In mobile resolutions). This issue is only on the mobile resolutions of 900 and under. In firefox I am able to to press crtl+shift+m to view the different resolutions.

which file should I look into or go about doing this to have this possible?

Hopefully I was able to explain this correctly.

Thank you